# How to properly sanitize strings for update_option()

Tags: plugin-development, options

I've tried to import an option value via update_options($name, $value) where $value has special characters (like apostrophe's for example) and I've noticed that the apostrophe gets stripped out of the text before it reaches the database.

What is the suggested sanitization of strings prior to sending them to update_options()?

Comment: It should work with apostrophes just fine. This seems like a configuration issue or bug introduced by something, rather than native behavior. Note that inline documentation states that `update_option()` explicitly expects input to **not** be SQL-escaped.

Comment: could you please include specific example? It's waste of time to guess. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `esc_html( $string )` ([Codex ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html)), which among other things encodes single- and double-quotes.

For further reference, see the [Data Validation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) entry in the Codex.

Answer (score 4):

You should not use esc functions for data that's going into the database.  esc functions are for output only.

The update_option() function sanitizes for you, so there's no need to run any extra san functions.

Comment: You're correct about esc functions being for display. However, as @ARWVISIONS mentioned in his answer, while update_option() *does* run sanitize_option(), if you follow through and review sanitize_option() you'll find that it only sanitizes specifically pre-determined options. Anything not in that list passes through unsanitized.

Comment: @butlerblog No, that's not correct. If you see the `update_option` function code, around at line 412, you'll see this `$value = sanitize_option( $option, $value );` without any conditions, so, `update_option` sanitizes everything; maybe it's serialization that got you confused because it doesn't serialize everything just non-scaler values. The `$value` parameter also has a comment **"Expected to not be SQL-escaped"**.

Comment: @Christos You're assuming `sanitize_option()` sanitizes every option sent to it, but **it does not** (and it explicitly states this in the docs). Please reread my comment above carefully: `sanitize_option()` "only sanitizes specifically pre-determined options." It uses a switch with no default, so anything not in the list is returned unsanitized unless you specifically set up a filter for that value. If you have something custom or otherwise not in the list, you **cannot** assume that it is sanitized, which is part of what led to the WordPress AMP exploit noted in @ARWVISIONS answer.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on Chris Flannagans answers so... update_options() does not sanitize all options. Some core options are sanitized, but custom option are not. You must sanitize the input yourself.

https://www.wordfence.com/blog/2018/11/xss-injection-campaign-exploits-wordpress-amp-plugin/

Comment: update_option() *does* sanitize all options. If you use update_option(), the very first thing that it does is sanitize the $value. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/

Comment: they how come i can insert full calls to scripts and complete HTML tags  using update_option?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_option/

Not all options are sanitized by sanitize_option()

Comment: Good point! Looks like sanitize_option() just handles what's pre-determined. That's definitely something that should be noted in your answer. You should edit your answer to emphasize this (as not everyone reads comments). It does  provide a filter at the end, so sanitize_option_{$option} could be set up for any of those, but it's probably easier to just sanitize before sending it to update_option().

Comment: It does sanitize everything and the parameter `$value` also has a [comment](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/) **"Expected to not be SQL-escaped"**.

Comment: Christos - Can you explain your answer? How does the function sanitize custom options?

Comment: You stated in another comment that update_option calls sanitize_option on line 421, but sanitize_option does not sanitize all options. 

Look here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_option/

Existing options handled by sanitize_option():

Comment: @Christos - I think you're only looking at `update_option()` and seeing that it runs `santitize_option()` on everything and then assuming that `sanitize_option()` **actually** sanitizes everything that is sent to it. `sanitize_option()` **only sanitizes a specific list of options.** Anything not on that list must be handled with a custom filter or sanitized before you run `update_option()`. Based on the function name, you'd think that it sanitizes everything, but that's a dangerous assumption (see @ARWVISIONS note of the WordPress AMP XSS exploit above).

Comment: @butlerblog @ARWVISIONS you're both correct. I actually didn't know there is a bunch of `sanitize_*` built-in functions that each covers a different case. Thanks for the clarification.